# NumberFormatException method

Tags: java, swing, awt, numberformatexception

Hello everyone, I'd like to ask someone to help me. I want to write a method in the same class to use `NumberFormatException` that takes the value of a `JTextField` and checks if it is number and prints. Also, how do I implement this code in the `actionPerformed` method?

This the main method

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JavaApplication19 is = new JavaApplication19("title");
        is.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This the GUI class:

```
public class JavaApplication19 extends JFrame{
    private final JButton button;
    private final JTextField text;
    private final JLabel lable;



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */ 
    public JavaApplication19(String title){
        setSize(500, 200);
        setTitle(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JavaApplication19.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button = new JButton("enter only number or i will kill you");
        text = new JTextField();
        lable = new JLabel("numbers only");
        JPanel rbPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        rbPanel.add(button);
        rbPanel.add(text);
        rbPanel.add(lable);

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.add(rbPanel);

        button.addActionListener(new ButtonWatcher());

        private class ButtonWatcher implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
            Object buttonPressed=a.getSource();
            if(buttonPressed.equals(button))
            { 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use `try/catch` blocks?

Comment: `try { something } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { do something }`

Comment: yes it most be try/catch and it most be method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(buttonPressed.equals(button))
{
    try {
        //  try something
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The `// try something` should be the code where you're getting the input text and parsing (ex `Integer.parseInt(textField.getText())`). If the parse doesn't work because something than a number is not entered, it will throw a `NumberFormatException`

See [Exceptions tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) if you need more information on how to use exceptions

**Edit: Method**

Something simple like this would work

```
public int parseInput(String input) throws NumberFormatException {
    return Integer.parseInt(input); 
}
```

Or something like this if you want to catch the exception

```
public static int parseInput(String input) {
    int number = 0;
    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(input); 
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        someLabel.setText("Must be a number");
        return -1;  // return 0 
    }
}
```

Then in your actionPerformed you can do something like this

```
if(buttonPressed.equals(button))
{
    int n;
    if (parseInput(textField.getText()) != -1){
        n = parseInput(textField.getText());
        // do something with n
    }
}
```

**Edit: boolean Method**

```
public boolean isNumber(String input){
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()){
        if (!Character.isDigit(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usage

```
if(buttonPressed.equals(button))
{
    if (isNumber(textField.getText()){
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Edit: or to `catch` exception**

```
public boolean isNumber(String input){
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(input);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think it most be method that take one argument which is the value of the text field and return true if it is true and false if it's false

Comment: can you show me how you will implement it in the code other thing it most return true if it is true and false if it is false

Comment: I edited with a boolean method. But it does not make use of the `NumberFormatException` if that was the requirement. Just place the method in your class, and you can use it.

Comment: I just edited with a method using the `NumberFormatException`. You have many options to work with. Choose one.

Comment: The method should be placed in the class, outside of the constructor.

Comment: if it is false it should show JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("you most write number")

Comment: can i have your email

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42764/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-isslam-akkilah)

Comment: @peeskillet Hey, negative numbers are also numbers :-)